# How to make the type checking at compile time?

Tags: scala, types, traits

In [`TraversableOnce`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L307), there is a `sum` method that is only usable if the contained type is `Numeric` (else it won't compile). I wonder if this is usable for other case (to avoid runtime check).

In particular the case where we have two traits A and B. We want to have a method `f` that can be used only if the object inherits **both** A and B. But not if it extends only one of them. I don't want to make another `trait AB extends A with B`. I just want to be unable to use `f` if not both traits are inherited.

```
package com.example

trait Base
trait Foo extends Base {
  def g = println("foo bar " + toString)
}
trait Bar extends Base {
  /* If this is both Foo and Bar, I can do more */
  def f = {
    if (!this.isInstanceOf[Foo]) error("this is not an instance of Foo")
    this.asInstanceOf[Foo].g
  }
}
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    object ab extends Foo with Bar
    object ba extends Bar with Foo
    object b extends Bar
    ab.f
    ba.f
    // I don't want next line to compile:
    try { b.f } catch { case e: RuntimeException => println(e) }
  }
}
```

EDIT: solution, thanks to @Aaron Novstrup

```
trait Bar extends Base { self =>
  def f(implicit ev: self.type <:< Foo) = {
    //self.asInstanceOf[Foo].g // [1]
    ev(this).g // [2]
  }
}
```

Now in `main`, `b.f` doesn't compile. Nice

EDIT 2: changed line [1] to [2] reflect changes in answer by @Aaron Novstrup

EDIT 3: without using `self` reflect changes in answer by @Aaron Novstrup

```
trait Bar extends Base {
  /* If this is both Foo and Bar, I can do more */
  def f(implicit ev: this.type <:< Foo) = {
    ev(this).g
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `ev` parameter to avoid the cast -- it's a `Function1[self.type, Foo]`. Updated my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
trait A {
   def bar = println("I'm an A!")
}

trait B { 
   def foo(implicit ev: this.type <:< A) = { 
      ev(this).bar
      println("and a B!")
   }
}
```

The compiler will only be able to supply the `evidence` parameter if the object's static type (at the call site) extends `A`.

Comment: Nice, it's working, thanks. First time I see a self not used to force an inheritance chain, but to suggest improvement. And hence, first time I can't do without.

Comment: Actually, the self type is unnecessary.  You can just use `this`.

Comment: @pedrofurla Nope. `ev` has the type `<:<[this.type, A]`, which extends `Function1[this.type, A]`.

Comment: well in fact this time the `{self =>` is also doable differently

Comment: I had never realized that <:< extends Function1. That's a remarkably important piece of information.

Comment: Personally, I pronounce it "extends" or "inherits", just like the `<:` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing that the signature of sum is

```
def sum [B >: A] (implicit num: Numeric[B]) : B
```

You seem to be assuming that number types extends [*Numeric*](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/math/Numeric.scala#L1), this is not true. Actually they are implicitly converted to *Numeric*, in the case of *Int* the implicit used is *scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral* which define operations like *plus* and *times*.

So the restriction on what types of *A* a *TraversableOnce[A].sum* is allowed is achieved by the existence of implicit provinding the required operations.

This is just a quick explanation of the overall workings of Numeric and type classes. For more check the sources of math.Numeric.XisY, math.Integral and math.Fractional and how type classes works: [implicit-tricks-type-class-pattern](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2010/06/implicit-tricks-type-class-pattern.html) and [type-class-pattern-example](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2010/06/type-class-pattern-example.html).

Comment: This isn't _quite_ correct, but it's close.  There is no implicit conversion from `Int` to `Numeric[Int]`, but there is an implicit `Numeric[Int]` object in scope (namely, `IntIsIntegral`) that allows the compiler to supply the implicit parameter to the `sum` method.